# Layout C# not working on content pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am having a problem where my WebPages Razor website's layout C# code isn't running on the layout's content pages, and I can't figure out why. I asked this question recently and got an answer, however, I'm sure there's a way to make the layout's C# code run on content pages because I've made another site which I recently checked if it did the same thing, but on that site it works perfectly fine. I don't understand why.

The reason I need this, is to check if a user is logged in and if a user is in a specific role, and if they're not in both, it needs to redirect them to the login page. The code itself works if I put it in the specific page's C# code, but from my own understanding it should definitely also run if it's being put in the layout page's C# code.

As I said, I've done this on another site, and I'm driving myself crazy trying to find out why it works on the other site I made, and not on this one I'm currently making.

_AdminLayout.cshtml page for the site it doesn't work on:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("bsdinvest");

    var accountLocked = db.QueryValue("SELECT AccountLocked FROM Users WHERE UserID = @0", WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);

    if (accountLocked == 1) {
        Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Locked");
    }

    if (!Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin")) {
        Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Default");
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/admin.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/Admin/Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Admin/Accounts/Default">User Accounts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Admin/News/List">News</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="/Admin/Logout">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        @RenderBody();
        <footer>
            <p>Powered by <a href="http://mikzercoding.com">NM-Development</a></p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Dashboard page within the admin panel, which the layout page's C# code is supposed to also run on:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Admin/_AdminLayout.cshtml";

    var db = Database.Open("bsdinvest");

    var user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = @0", WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Dashboard - Admin Area</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content-container">
            <h2>Welcome back, @user.FirstName @user.LastName</h2>
            <h3>Notes</h3>
            <a href="/Admin/Notes/List">All notes</a> | <a href="/Admin/Notes/Add">Add note</a>
            @foreach (var row in db.Query("SELECT TOP 5 * FROM AdminNotes ORDER BY DateTime DESC")) {
                <div class="text-wrap">
                    <a href="@Href("~/Admin/Notes/Edit", row.ID)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                    <a href="@Href("~/Admin/Notes/Delete", row.ID)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                    <h4>@row.Heading</h4>
                    @Html.Raw(row.Text)
                    <p class="bottom-line">Written by: @row.Author, on: @row.DateTime</p>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you also want to see the same files for the site which it actually works on, please just let me know and I will provide it.

Thank you in advance, and I apologize for the long text in this question.

Please help me!

Comment: Side note: it is very strange that both layout and corresponding page render complete HTML (with html/head/body tags)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I'm not sure I understand what you mean? Is it not supposed to? I'm sorry I'm still very much in the learning phase of this subject, I'm quite a newbie.

Comment: Look at the `_AdminLayout.cshtml` Page and see where `@RenderBody()` is defined. That's where the "content" will go - so your "content" page, is again declaring an entire HTML document (another `<head/>`, `<body/>`, etc.. It should only be the `<div/>`...Hth...

Comment: I also have a similar issue. I have an authentication if/else in my layout page containing the Renderbody() or a redirect. For some reason, when I run my app locally in VS it occasionally doesn't work. If I place a breakpoint on the if statement it doesn't activate.